# mongodb collection count wrong in "show log" getmore

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I run the `mongo` shell, I get this result when I count the values in the `connected` collection.

```
> db.connected.find({}).count()
10326
```

But when I run a `node.js` query on the database:

```
dbConnector.open(function(err, db) {
    db.collection('connected').find().toArray(function(err, items)
```

The log in `mongo` the `show log` says `nreturned: 10225` for a query sent from

```
<2015/09 etc> [conn165] getmore mydb.connected cursorid:NNNNN ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 14 locks(micros) r:5283 nreturned:10225 reslen:1015981 212ms
```

I tried to `reIndex` the collection named `connection`, but this did not make any difference. Which other admin commands should I try or how should I go about looking for this problem?

### EDIT 0

I deleted the first two thirds of this database before this issue turned up.

After consulting with a more mongodb knowledgeable developer who could not find the root cause, it was decided to drop the collection. With new values inserted into the mongodb collection, it works normally again.

Comment: Are you sure you're on the right db? `db.getName()`.

Comment: @ThomasStringer yes, I am positive I am on the right db. That is the only db with a collection named `connection`.